# SceneKit Move Camera

Tags: camera, scenekit, move

There is a big scene,eg:a house ,I want to use TapGes to move camera to see different rooms. Now I have two questions:

1.I can not get the 3D point from this tapPoint in the scene

2. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples that may help.

57018359 - this post one tells you how to touch a 2d screen (tap) and translate it to 3d coordinates with you deciding the depth (z), like if you wanted to tap the screen and place an object in 3d space.

57003908 - this post tells you how to select an object with a hitTest (tap).  For example, if you showed the front of a house with a door and tap it, then the function would return your door node provided you name the node "door" and took some kind of action when it's touched.  Then you could reposition your camera based on that position.  You'll want to go iterate through all results because there might be overlapping or plus Z nodes

55129224 - this post gives you quick example of creating a camera class.  You can use this to reposition your camera or move it forward and back, etc.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Here is my code:<pre><code>- (void)tap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGes {
    CGPoint tapL = [tapGes locationInView:self.scnView];
    SCNVector3 projectedOrigin = [self.scnView projectPoint:SCNVector3Zero];
    SCNVector3 vpWithZ = SCNVector3Make(tapL.x,tapL.y,projectedOrigin.z);
    SCNVector3 worldPoint = [self.scnView unprojectPoint:vpWithZ];
    self.camera1Node.position = worldPoint;
    self.lastPoint = worldPoint; </pre></code>but my camera do not forward,pls help me check if there is any problem,thanks

Comment: Could be a bunch of things and I can't tell from this.  An easy way is to make sure your camera is working first.  Used fixed points for eye and focus - make sure it's pointed to the right spot - then move the eye position to X-15 or something like that, then run it.  Also do a console print to make sure your tap gesture is working.